# Pricing for room management service

Tags: pricing, b2b

I'm working on a project which includes several services for room management. The client currently has no upfront pricing on there website, instead opting for phone/email/request a demo for companies to discover the pricing - this is a similar trend seen in their competitors.

My question is whether a **pricing page** would benefit the business. I'm conflicted between two ideas, the first that it's probably best to show pricing upfront a be honest with the customer (or perceived as honest at least) and the second being that with this is a product used by business's such as banks and logistic services so needs to appear professional. The second point is important - this service needs to stand apart from the typical startup app pricing page, it's not a singular app, more a service which integrates into an existing business model.

I guess a simpler way of putting it is: does upfront pricing work for B2B?

Comment: Compare Regus (old school B2B, 'call us for pricing) http://www.regus.com/us/day-offices versus WeWork ('startup', B2B, pricing up front) https://www.wework.com/locations/london

Comment: Whilst visitors to the site might appreciate pricing, in my experience with B2B there isn't really such as thing as 'the' price. It heavily depends on the client, requirements, competitors and a whole wealth of other factors. This makes it more of a Business Requirements issue than a UX one I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will depend on the way your company does business.

I design B2B solutions and we do not show prices on our website. A sales team will work with prospective buyers and will negotiate the price based on many factors, e.g. volume (number of user seats, or number of CPUs), scope, professional services, etc.

This situation is what typically differentiates B2B from B2C.